# BigSur - Putting a white border around all windows from all applications?

Tags: windows, ui

I'm running `Big Sur 11.6.5`.

I'd like to configure my Mac's user interface so that each and every window that will ever appear on my desktop (not the dock) will have a thin white border, or at least light grey.

Is there any way to do this? ... perhaps with a 3rd-party utility?

I know there are ways to do this for certain specific applications, but I would like this border to always appear on each and every window on my desktop for all applications.

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions.

**UPDATE**: (from my comment below)

The reason I want this is because I tend to have several terminal windows open on my screen. I like my desktop to have a plain black background, and I like a plain black background on my terminal windows. Having an easily recognizable border on my windows makes it less likely that I'd mistakenly type in the wrong window. I run this way under Windows and Linux, and I prefer the same under MacOS, if possible. I know I could use different colors or different window-placement strategies, but that is undesirable for me. I guess I'm out of luck under MacOS.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to do this?

Comment: Can you list some of the applications that do this? MacOS's UI is not designed to be heavily customizable. Any such patch is likely to be unstable as changes are made to the OS internals.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The reason I want this is because I tend to have several terminal windows open on my screen. I like my desktop to have a plain black background, and I like a plain black background on my terminal windows. Having an easily recognizable border on my windows makes it less likely that I'd mistakenly type in the wrong window. I run this way under Windows and Linux, and I prefer the same under MacOS, if possible. I know I could use different colors or different window-placement strategies, but that is undesirable for me. I guess I'm out of luck under MacOS.